# IOS String length comparison issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm struggling with an if Comparison - I basically want to make two comparisons - both of which need to pass - Firstly a basic if a string variable is equal to 'rec' and secondly if a strings character limit is not equal to zero.

I've tried various combinations - but this is where i'm at at the mo..

```
 ArticleObject *A = [self.articleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
 NSInteger imglength = [A.arImage length];

 if([A.arRec isEqual: @"rec"] ) && (imglength !=Nil){
     return 195;
 }
 else return 50;
```

I get an expected identifier error on the (imglength comparison - as in this screen shot
[image]

Can anyone shed any light for me please?

Comment: Just a syntactic observation, you shouldn't be comparing integral values with `Nil` or `nil`.  You should be comparing them to `0`.  A nil value refers to a non-existent object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things you should change:

```
ArticleObject *A = self.articleArray[indexPath.section];
NSInteger imglength = [A.arImage length];

if (imglength && [A.arRec isEqualToString:@"rec"]) {
     return 195;
} else {
     return 50;
}
```

Don't use `Nil` (or `nil`) with primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

Your parentheses are messed up:

```
if([A.arec isEqualToString:@"rec"] && (imglengyb !=Nil))
                                                      ^--------------//here
```

Maybe a better way would be:

```
if([A.arec isEqualToString:@"rec"] && [[A.arImage length] != 0])
```

Comment: spot on - cheers @meda that woks fine,all now cool apart from a warning - comparison between pointer and integer (nsInteger) and void

Comment: so deleting my similar answer with a downvote magically seems to have given you a rep point. Seems you downvote me to up your answer. Care to explain?